# Thunderbird Cannot Create Profile error

Tags: 14.04, thunderbird, email

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 x64bit and I try to run Mozilla Thunderbird in order to manage my email accounts !

Whenever I open it and try to create a profile I get the following ***error*** :

```
Profile couldn't be created. Probably the chosen folder isn't writable.
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED) [nsIToolkitProfileService.createProfile]"  nsresult: "0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://mozapps/content/profile/createProfileWizard.js :: onFinish :: line 196"  data: no]
```

[image]

I tried to remove the profiles.ini file in `~/.thunderbird` folder but nothing , change folder profile name (instead of Default User , to something else) again nothing ..

Anyone can help me out ? Thanks in Advance

Comment: What are the ownerships / permissions on the relevant directories? You can list them from a terminal e.g. using `ls -al ~/.thunderbird/`

Comment: Obviously the app doesn't have an access to a file. Unfortunately the error message doesn't print what the file it trying to access, but you can easily find it → just launch the thunderbird with `strace` program. It does prints system calls; somewhere higher the system call which prints the error you would see a call that trying to use a file with `Permission denied` error.

Comment: You were right .. i just removed from the ~/.cache folder the thunderbird folder and when i started thunderbird i got no error :-)) `access("/home/rel0aded/.cache/thunderbird/v1wb1dmb.default", F_OK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
mkdir("/home/rel0aded/.cache/thunderbird/v1wb1dmb.default", 0700) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)`
 add it as an answer so i can vote it for you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested the @User1911 to use `strace` to find the system call that is failing with `Permission denied` error — there would be written the path to a problem file.

They got the output

```
access("/home/rel0aded/.cache/thunderbird/v1wb1dmb.default", F_OK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
mkdir("/home/rel0aded/.cache/thunderbird/v1wb1dmb.default", 0700) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

And removing the `~/.cache/thunderbird` directory worked.

Comment: Basically I  just removed ~/.cache/thunderbird directory ! and worked but it's pretty much the same  :-)

Comment: @User1911 ah, I'll edit it ☺

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround could be running Thunderbird as a super user:

`sudo thunderbird`

Once the profile is created, you can close Thunderbird and proceed as usual.